# Voltage follower output half wave signal; how can I reduce the ringing on the output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, ringing, precision-rectifier

I have used a voltage follower with a [TSH082](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/32/74/01/e8/bf/0c/4c/9a/CD00003289.pdf/files/CD00003289.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003289.pdf). I was able to get a half-wave signal with some slight ringing on the output (shown below).

Is there a way to reduce the ringing on the half-wave signal output?

**Single Supply Voltage follower**

[image]
[image: Signal Measurement]

**Single Supply inverting amplifier:**

[image]
[image]

I have used a precision rectifier, and I unable to get a half wave signal.

**Using a single supply precision half wave rectifier:**
[image]

Comment: Does your circuit use a bypass capacitor on the power supply?

Comment: @qrk it has a bypass capacitor of 0.1uF between the +5V to GND.

Comment: What is your system objective - rectification at high speed is difficult. Are you intending to get amplitude? Or is it specially for wave-shaping? There may be other ways to achieve your objective.

Comment: @KevinWhite I want to get a half wave signal of the input.

Comment: @Sam - yes, but why? What is the system objective. Maybe that is achievable without getting the half-wave rectified version. It is rare to need a half-wave rectified signal. Are you trying to get the average amplitude of the signal for example?

Comment: @Sam - do you mean the instantaneous amplitude or the average amplitude? Are you going to filter the signal after the rectification then compare?

Comment: @KevinWhite the main reason: I have two branches, where one branch is constant amplitude sine wave and the other branch is varying. When I do differential of two branch, the moment the varying branch amplitude is lower than the other constant amplitude branch, the output signal inverts which I don't want. Therefore, the idea is to only take the halfwave signal of both branches, and do differential. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @KevinWhite i think its instantaneous amplitude; just to be sure, its given Voltage peak at that moment.

Comment: @Sam - what is supposed to happen on the negative half-cycle?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need a rectifier at all - just a comparator and multiplexer.

Comment: @KevinWhite can I possible talk to you virtually. In differential amplifier, when the branch with constant amplitude is higher than the varying branch, the output of the differential branch inverts; I want to avoid that.  I only want an output when the varying amplitude branch is higher than the constant amplitude branch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133715/discussion-between-kevin-white-and-sam).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are driving the outputs to create a half-wave rectification in an unstable manner.

This Op Amp has GBW = 100 MHz with 40 deg phase margin when loaded with 150 ohms// 30 pF yet your results are different.

**Assertion:** This design is a poor method of rectification for high speed.

This is what happens when the output saturates and the input is no longer a virtual ground or an error amplifier with a null input operating in the linear region.  Effectively the gain is always 0 when the output is saturated then the input approaches the null input and the non-linear gain  goes to near 80 dB of linear gain open loop with unity gain closed loop.

- Diode saturation capacitance and reverse recovery time also influence the results and thus keeping C in the low pF and reducing R without current limiting will help.

**Essentially the Op Amp has less phase margin coming out of saturation.**

**Recommendation:**

- Use a bipolar supply or bias the output to keep the inputs & outputs active in the linear range. (see schematic below)
- use an analog switch and comparator to rectify the signal.
- try a suitable pull-up resistor on the output to pre-bias the output current.
- try a 150 ohm load to dampen the response of the high side driver

[image]

- other designs, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323729597_Minimum_component_high_frequency_current_mode_rectifier

[image]

and YET another Design
[image]

Comment: I want to let you know that I have tried the above circuit design before but it did not work out. is there a specific type of diode that we need to use for precision half wave rectifier? I will try the circuit again with TSH82, and post the result. Thank you

Comment: The lowest capacitance small signal diodes and check impedance ratio at slew rate

Comment: I have tried both the circuitry, and I am unable to get half wave rectifier; I have uploaded the signal in the post, and added few more info. I can get a half wave signal using a non-inverting amplifier or inverting amplifier with slight ringing; would that help with stability.